# Additional primary key constraints on association object when specifying relationship in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a many to many relationship that has a specific set of characteristics. I thought I could implement this in sqlalchemy with an association table as below:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, Unicode, Enum

import enum

Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode)

    worksAt = relationship('Address', secondary='parelationship')
    manages = relationship('Address', secondary='parelationship')
    resides = relationship('Address', secondary='parelationship')
    ## How do I specify the additional constraint of 
    ## parelationship.relation = Relationships.resident?

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode)

class Relationships(enum.Enum):
    resident = 1
    worker = 2
    manager = 3

class PersonAddressRelationship(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parelationship'
    personId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
    adressID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('address.id'), primary_key=True)
    relation = Column(Enum(Relationships), primary_key=True)
```

Is there a neat way of specifying the `worksAt`, `manages`, `resides` relationships (and equally `worksHere`, `isManagedBy` etc in the Address table)?

Answer (score 1):

Either define the [`primaryjoin`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) or the [`secondaryjoin`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.secondaryjoin) with the additional predicate, or use a derived table as secondary.

Using a derived table:

```
worksAt = relationship(
    'Address',
    secondary=lambda:
        PersonAddressRelationship.__table__.select().
            where(PersonAddressRelationship.relation == Relationships.worker).
            alias(),
    viewonly=True)
```

Using `primaryjoin`:

```
manages = relationship(
    'Address', secondary='parelationship',
    primaryjoin=lambda:
        and_(Person.id == PersonAddressRelationship.personId,
             PersonAddressRelationship.relation == Relationships.manager),
    viewonly=True)
```

Using `secondaryjoin`:

```
resides = relationship(
    'Address', secondary='parelationship',
    secondaryjoin=lambda:
        and_(Address.id == PersonAddressRelationship.adressID,
             PersonAddressRelationship.relation == Relationships.manager),
    viewonly=True)
```

Note that in all the examples the expression is passed as a callable (a lambda), so that it can be lazily evaluated during mapper configuration.

Comment: These work for lookups, but not for adding new relationships such as `aPerson.manages.append(Address(name='Office Building'))`. Can this be integrated?